# Dirtree and lstset side by side

Tags: floats, listings, minipage, dirtree

A `\dirtree` and a `\lstset` should be shown side by side. With the code below the `\dirtree` is vertically not on the same level as the `\lstset` (above the `\dirtree` is some empty space). How can I fix that?

Any help is appreciated.

Minimal code:

```
 \begin{minipage}[hbt]{.5\linewidth}
    \dirtree{% 
      .1 /.
      .2 Directory1.
      .3 Directory2.
      .2 Directory3.
    }
    \captionof{figure}{A directory structure.}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[hbt]{.5\linewidth}
    \lstset{language=java}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Hello World., captionpos=b, label={lst:javacode}]
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please expand your code snippet to [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing the optional arguments to `minipage` with those to `figure`.

The optional argument to `minipage` can consist of only one character, `t` (top alignment) or `b` (bottom alignment). It could also be `c`, but it's the default anyway. In my example I use center alignment, it can also be bottom with `\begin{minipage}[b]{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree,listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\dirtree{%
  .1 /.
  .2 Directory1.
  .3 Directory2.
  .2 Directory3.
}
\caption{A directory structure.}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
\lstset{language=java}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Hello World., captionpos=b, label={lst:javacode}]
System.out.println("Hello World!");
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]